# Make use of "gfx_switch_status" in sony-laptop?

Tags: scripts, hardware, nvidia-optimus, vaio

I successfully managed to install 14.04.3 on my Sony Vaio S Series SVS1513C5E laptop and after few minor tweaks I adore the setup!

My concern here is:

The device has Optimus graphics that uses a hardware switch (Windows 7-8) to change between Intel and Nvidia card. 
On Ubuntu, I have Nvidia Prime with quick switch indicator all set up to change it via software, but I'm wondering if there is a slight possibility to add the commands:

`sudo prime-select nvidia` and `sudo prime-select intel`

as executable script when changing between SPEED and STAMINA mode via that hardware switch?

There is a file in `sony-laptop` folder named `gfx_switch_status` that reacts on the switch and changes the "one word" in the file from `stamina` to `speed` and that's it.

So the hardware switch is being recognized, the file content is edited accordingly, how can I control what happens when it changes?

Thanks for any help on that ;)

EDIT: `acpi_listen` shows following hardware changes when moving the switch:
`root@UbuntuOne:~$ acpi_listen`

`sony/hotkey SNY5001:00 00000003 00000000`

`sony/hotkey SNY5001:00 00000003 00000001`

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this method but you can try it.

Open a terminal and type : `sudo gedit /etc/acpi/events/sonyswitch`

Make the contents :

```
event=sony/hotkey
action=zenity --info --text=%e
```

Save the file.

Open a terminal and type : `sudo apt-get install zenity` to install zenity

Restart ACPI with "kill -SIGHUP `pidof acpid`"

Move the switch to both SPEED and STAMINA and write down what the message box says for both

Open `gedit` and type :

```
#/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "WHAT THE MESSAGE BOX SAID FOR SPEED" ]
   sudo prime-select nvidia


if [ "$1" == "WHAT THE MESSAGE BOX SAID FOR STAMINA" ]
   sudo prime-select Intel
```

Save the file in `~/vaioswitch` and open a terminal and run `chmod +x ~/vaioswitch`

Open a terminal and type : `sudo gedit /etc/acpi/events/sonyswitch`

Edit the contents to

Change line 2 to  `action=/home/YOUUSERNAME/vaioswitch %e`

Fix any syntax errors in the script and reboot you computer.It should work now